# Java Compare two lists and create two list one found and another one not found

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to compare two lists in java and build two lists oneFound and another one NotFound.

Here's my code so far, can you please advice for the best results and efficient way to do it.

So bascially i am getting a list of emails to be added or update. Now what i am try to achieve is I want to check those emails against the ones in the DB. if they exist in DB then simply update them otherwise add them.

For that I get the list of emails from the DB and then try to compare that list with the list of emails which are to be added or updated.

Then I build 2 lists one Found and another one not found. The foundones are updated and not found ones are which will be inserted into DB.

The following code builds not found with the lists which are already in db resulting in the DB insertion (causing duplicate records).

So if I correctly build found and notfound then the update and insertion will be working correctly.

```
public updateData (List<String> emailToAddList, List<String> emailToDeleteList) 
{

    List<String> emailsFromDB = Service.getEmailsFromDB();
    List<String> emailToUpdateFound = new ArrayList<String>( );
    List<String> emailToUpdateNotFound = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
    **  compare emailToAddList with emailsFromDB, if found populate 
    **  emailToUpdateFound for data update, otherwise populate emailToUpdateNotFound for data insetion
    **/

    Collections.sort(emailListToAdd);
    Collections.sort(emailListfromDB);

    if(emailListToAdd.size() > emailListfromDB.size()
    {
    for(String addStr: emailListToAdd)
    {
        if(emailListfromDB.contains(addStr))
        {
            emailToUpdateFound.add(addStr);
        }
        else
        {
            emailToUpdateNotFound.add(addStr);
        }
    }

    }
    else
    { 
        for(String str: emailListfromDB)
        {
            if(emailListToAdd.contains(str))
            {
                emailToUpdateFound.add(str);
            }
            else
            {
                emailToUpdateNotFound.add(str);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: On SO you will get better help if you tell us what isn't working.  Just posting code and saying "Help" without explaining what you don't understand is not considered good form.  Please edit your post and include why you need help.  What is it doing that you don't understand?

Comment: Just a thought about the line 'if(emailListToAdd.size() > emailListfromDB.size()'. So the assumption is that the former is a super-set of the latter? So there can never be a case that they are of the same length but listToAdd has an address that is not in the DB?

Comment: Also, how large are you expecting these lists to be? I'm thinking you could actually fire a couple of queries (or nested queries) to the DB and get the whole thing done.

Comment: Thanks Sagar, Well the DB is oracle and the lists size may vary. The else part is if both are equal or if the ones from the DB are larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will like the [org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.subtract(a,b)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#subtract(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)) method. This addresses your requirement in a simple way.

Here's my sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    input.add("a");
    input.add("b");
    input.add("c");
    input.add("d");

    List<String> existing = new ArrayList<String>();
    existing .add("d");
    existing .add("b");
    existing .add("z"); 

    Collection<String> newStuff = CollectionUtils.subtract(input, existing);
    Collection<String> updateStuff = CollectionUtils.subtract(input,newStuff);

    System.out.println(newStuff);
    System.out.println(updateStuff);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the example helped and serves my purpose. Thanks for everyone for their time and suggestions, If i have any issues. I will back or ask.

Answer (score 4):

Judicious use of [removeAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) and [retainAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) is *way* simpler than what you're trying.

```
Collection<String> c1;
Collection<String> c2;
c1.removeAll(c2); // set of elements in c1 not in c2
c1.retainAll(c2); // set of elements in c1 also in c2
```

Comment: So how would I apply this in my case which one will be c1 and which one will be c2. Can you please answer. Thanks

Comment: I do have to populate both c1 and c2, how do i get the list emailToUpdateFound  and emailToUpdateNotFound

Answer (score 0):

Treat each list as a queue.  Load the "head" of each queue in a variable.  Loop, examining the two head values.  If left > right, left is unique (assuming you started with the lowest), so put it in the list of unique left entries, then reload left with a new value from the left list.  Likewise if right > left only the other way around.  If left == right then you have a match -- put them in the list of matches, then refresh both variables.

Keep this up until one list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a unique key to the email column, and then just insert anything. If the email already exist then the DB will ignore it. Then there is no need to compare 2 lists.

Comment: The DB uses sequence and it's not up to me to change it. I can do it programmatically on my side to achieve insert and update.

Answer (score 0):

To approach the problem in another way...

As more an more emails are put into the database, it may become unwieldy to get the entire list from the database and then run the comparison.

If you don't need to know what emails were actually added, you can use an `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (or the equivalent depending on your database) to add the entire list to the database.

If you do need to know which emails you're adding, you can do a `SELECT WHERE email IN (list of new emails)` to retrieve the ones that already exist, and then subtract that list from the ones your have to get the ones that don't exist. Extending it even further, you can create a temp table, put all the emails in it, and then remove the ones that do exist via a similar query.

The above two solutions assume that the database list grows to a large number, whereas the new emails list remains at a smaller size.

Comment: The query with in clause is possible. All the logic i have to do is programmatically as I can't change the DB schema.